# C# DateTime converts after using at ToString();

Tags: c#, datetime

I have looked, but I cannot find an explanation for this.

startDate gives me "2016-01-14 07:55:37"
endDate gives me "2016-01-15 07:55:37"

But what confuses me is that startDate should give me "2016-01-14 19:55:37" Right?
StartDate1 seems to be correct, but when i do a ToString(), with format it changes.

```
DateTime startDate1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12);
string startDate = startDate1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

string endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Had you used `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` rather than `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` it would have worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure you format your `startDate` not `endDate`? If your local time is bigger than `12:00`, you get the same date _even_ if you subtract `12` hour as a normal.

Comment: both startDate and endDate has been formatted to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

As we are dealing with less then 08:00 on the day, it should go back a day, but it just stay on the same day, and edit the "hour"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 24 hour format you need to use `HH`

```
string startDate = startDate1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

hh is used for 12 hours format and HH is for 24 hours format

```
   string startDate = startDate1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

   string endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```